# jQuery Cycle pagination with current/total slide

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle, pager

I'd like to build a jQuery Cycle slideshow with pagination in the format of "current_slide/total_slides" as seen [here](http://diary.chopard.com/precious-temptations-bejewelled-treats)

I'm assuming I'd use pageAnchorBuilder to show the current and total slide numbers and then onAfter to update the current slide number?

Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Comment: The answer you chose is actually incorrect.  You can embed your slides as any element inside your slide holder (ie <div><ul><li>...) therefore relying on counting children does not work except in the simplest cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using jQuery Cycle plugin.
Imagine that slides are an ordered list:

```
<ol class="slides">
    <li class="slide">...</li>
    ...
</ol>
<a id="prev"></a><span id="counter">1 / 1</span><a id="next"></a>
```

you can obtain the total number of slides by calling:

```
var total = $('.slides').children().length;
```

Then we need to update the counter after slide changes:

```
$('.slides').cycle({
    after(el) {
        const currentSlideNo = $(el).index();
        $('#counter').text(currentSlideNo + ' / ' + total);
    },
    prev: $('#prev'),
    next: $('#next'),
});
```

Comment: This may be a simple question...but your approach using index() returns a zero-based result...so my first image appears as "0 / 5".  Is there a way to use a 1-based counting method? Simply adding "+1" after index() doesn't seem to be reliable.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sure, didn't think of that. after $('#counter').text... change currentSlideNo to (currentSlideNo+1). It should work, if not, additional parseInt may be required.

Comment: using `$('#counter').text(currentSlideNo+1' / '+total);` results in an Unexpected string error.  I've worked around it by using 'onPrevNextEvent' instead of the 'after' function, and setting `var currentSlideNo = $(slideElement).index() +1;`

Comment: There's a typo... it should be `(currentSlideNo+1+' / '+total)` of course.

Comment: Working with `.index()` doesn't seem reliable. The `after` callback function gets the current slide in the `options` object. I think this works better.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to calculate the total and slideindex because the jquery cycle plugin will already return those to you in the after event.

```
 after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {

    $('#counter').text((options.currSlide + 1) + '/' + (options.slideCount));
 }
```

Here is a jsfidde: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/Dhqdc/2/

Comment: The other answer is actually incorrect as you can provide a selector to determine which elements are slides therefor  $().children won't work.  Better to use the plugin api